# Show/hide div with jQuery and AJAX not working properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to show a specific div depending on the result of a SQL query.

My issue is that I **can't get the divs to switch asynchronously.**
Right now the page needs to be refreshed for the div to get updated.

```
  <?php
  //SQL query

   if (foo) {
   ?>

   <div id="add<?php echo $uid ?>">
      <h2><a href="#" class="plus" ?>">Add to list!</a></h2>   
   </div>

   <?php
       } else { 
   ?>
  <div id="remove<?php echo $uid ?>">
     <h2><a href="#" class="minus" ?>">Delete!</a></h2>
  </div>

  <?php     
              }
  <?          


 <script type="text/javascript">
 //add to list

 $(function() {
 $(".plus").click(function(){
 var element = $(this);
 var I = element.attr("id");
 var info = 'id=' + I;
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "ajax_add.php",
 data: info,
 success: function(data){
 $('#add'+I).hide();
 $('#remove'+I).show();
 }
 });
 return false;
 });

 });
 </script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 //remove 
 $(function() {
 $(".minus").click(function(){
 var element = $(this);
 var I = element.attr("id");
 var info = 'id=' + I;
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "ajax_remove.php",
 data: info,
 success: function(data){
 $('#remove'+I).hide();
 $('#add'+I).show();
 }
 });

 return false;

 });

 });
 </script>
```

`ajax_add.php` and `ajax_remove.php` only contain some SQL queries.

What is missing for the div #follow and #remove to switch without having to refresh the page?

Comment: Console is showing errors?

Comment: Please format your code so it's readable and why are you using two document ready calls? Also, have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Yes i have checked the console, there is no error shown.

Comment: `if (foo) {` followed by html at the beginning of your code can't be right, unless you've omitted some PHP somewhere there. (Also, if I wrote a JS engine it would return a `WhitespaceError: insufficient indenting` on your code.)

Comment: @nnnnnn there is a SQL query right before if (foo) {

Comment: My point was that that `if` should be inside `<?php ... ?>` shouldn't it? It shouldn't be directly followed by `<div>...` You can help us to help you by making your example reasonably complete.

Comment: @nnnnnn This was an unintended mistake. I've fixed it. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I'm trying to show a specific div depending on the result of a SQL query"*

Your code doesn't seem to do anything with the results of the SQL query. Which div you hide or show in your Ajax success callbacks depends only on which link was clicked, not on the results of the query.

Anyway, your click handler is trying to retrieve the `id` attribute from an element that doesn't have one. You have:

```
$(".plus").click(function(){
  var element = $(this);
  var I = element.attr("id");
```

...where `.plus` is the anchor element which *doesn't have an `id`.* It is the anchor's containing div that has an `id` defined. You could use `element.closest("div").attr("id")` to get the `id` from the div, but I think you intended to define an `id` on the anchor, because you currently have an incomplete bit of PHP in your html:

```
<a href="#" class="plus" ?>">
                         ^-- was this supposed to be the id?
```

Try this:

```
<a href="#" class="plus" data-id="<?php echo $uid ?>">
```

And then:

```
 var I = element.attr("data-id");
```

Note also that you don't need two separate script elements and two document ready handlers, you can bind both click handlers from within the same document ready. And in your case since your two click functions do almost the same thing you can combine them into a single handler:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(".plus,.minus").click(function(){
      var element = $(this);
      var I = element.attr("data-id");
      var isPlus = element.hasClass("plus");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: isPlus ? "ajax_add.php" : "ajax_remove.php",
        data: 'id=' + I,
        success: function(data){
          $('#add'+I).toggle(!isPlus);
          $('#remove'+I).toggle(isPlus);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });    
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i upvoted you. When I click on #add, it disappears and #remove still doesn't show unless I refresh the page. What could explain this behavior?

Comment: And yes indeed, the anchor is supposed to have an ID!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just noticed that your php code only returns one or the other of the divs. So #remove doesn't show because it doesn't exist on the page. You'd need to either return them both initially and hide one from your document ready handler, or dynamically add #remove from your .plus ajax success handler. Or actually my preference would be to just use a single element and change its text rather than showing and hiding things.

Answer (score 1):

The way i like to do Ajax Reloading is by using 2 files.

- The first: the main file where you have all your data posted.
- The second: the ajax file where the tasks with the db are made.

Than it works like this:

in the Main file the user lets say clicks on a button.
and the button is activating a jQuery ajax function.
than the ajax file gets the request and post out (with "echo" or equivalent).
at this point the Main file gets a success and than a response that contains the results.
and than i use the response to change the entire HTML content of the certain div.

for example:

#### The jQuery ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',  // Type of request (can be POST or GET).
url: 'ajax.php', // The link to the Ajax file.
data: {
    'action':'eliran_update_demo', // action name, used when one ajax file handles many functions of ajax.
    'userId':uId, // Simple variable "uId" is a JS var.
    'postId':pId  // Simple variable "pId" is a JS var.
},
success:function(data) {
    $("#div_name").html(data); // Update the contents of the div
},
error: function(errorThrown){
    console.log(errorThrown); // If there was an error it can be seen through the console log. 
}
});
```

#### The PHP ajax function:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) ) {
    $userId = $_POST['userId']; // Simple php variable
    $postId = $_POST['postId']; // Simple php variable
    $action = $_POST['action']; // Simple php variable

    switch ($action) // switch: in case you have more than one function to handle with ajax.
    {
        case "eliran_update_demo":
                    if($userId == 2){
                echo 'yes';
            }
            else{
                echo 'no';
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

in that php function you can do whatever you just might want to !

 Just NEVER forget that you can do anything on this base.

#### Hope this helped you :)

if you have any questions just ask ! :)