# js - display DIV's from rows in a Table via clicking on Icon

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, dom

I have no real coding skills in js. What I am trying to do is in a table that has a hidden CVtxt field to display that info in a DOM outside of the table when clicking on an Action button.

The way I've structured the table is not a must if there is a better way to get the CVtxt info to a Dom I can do that as well. If there is a better way to assign the CVtext to a variable for js that can also work.

This page is written in php.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="RelatedTab">
                <table id="related" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive hover nowrap compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll">
                                    <label for="selectAll"></label>
                                </span>
                            </th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Job</th>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Tel</th>
                            <th>CV-hidden</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    ';
        foreach($objApi['Data'] as $row)
    {
            echo '<tr><td>
                                <span class="custom-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="options[]" value="1">
                                    <label for="checkbox1"></label>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        <td><a href="Thinq.php?i=' . $row['AppDataId'] . '">' . $row['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row['LastName'] . '</a></td><td> ' . $row['JobTitle'] . '</td><td> ' . $row['CompanyName'] . '</td><td> ' . $row['Telephone'] . '</td><td>' . $row['CvTxtField'] . '</td><td><a href="#viewCV" class="edit"><i class="fa fa-eye" data-toggle="tooltip" title="View"></i></a></td></tr>';
    }            
echo '
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
        <col id="#CvText" class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div>
        ';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic html JS example for you to hide / show code , I hope it helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myDIV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi melic, thanks for this but your example is to hide a DIV, what I have is a table with multiple rows, and I want to display data that is related to a row on a Div outside of the table depending on which row you select.

Comment: oh ok when you click on a row or when onmouseover you want to show the related data ?

Comment: if yes there is two ways to do that ; get all data by php and create teh tables but keep them hidden and use my simple code above to show them  or the second method use AJAX to get data on fly by php while using same example above

Comment: here is a link for you I hope this helps if not I will try to [Solution for data on fly Jquery/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678807/2822922)

Comment: I suggest you to give a little time for [For Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) there many easy samples and explanations there. Also If you have android phone you may like to install [SoloLearn](https://www.sololearn.com/)